# Крутящееся колесо SVG

Tags: javascript, svg, анимация

Необходимо сделать крутящийся круг из секторов.

В каждом секторе, а так же в центре показывается свой фон.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Есть два варианта, устроит любой:

1. Количество секторов задаётся константой в JavaScript, которую можно настроить (посложнее, но более интересно).
2. Решение с фиксированным количеством секторов.

Необходимо сделать решение не только технически верное, но и что бы смотрелось красиво.

Что бы не было мыслей что я на халяву хочу получить готовую работу, поясняю, что это задача для освоения технологий, которые мы делаем в [SVG чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/70612/svg-chat).

Comment: `Transform: rotate` через  `setInterval` не подходит?

Answer (score 5):

Смотреть желательно раскрыв на всю страницу.

Расчёт секторов делается через `JavaScript`.

```js
/* картинки для анимации  */
var images = ["https://i.stack.imgur.com/SaKBd.jpg", "https://i.stack.imgur.com/cyQar.jpg", "https://i.stack.imgur.com/gzQrR.jpg", "https://i.stack.imgur.com/cyQar.jpg", "https://i.stack.imgur.com/1KW4v.jpg"];

var svg = document.getElementById("svg");
var all = document.getElementById("all");
var svgNS = "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg";

/* шаблон анимации поворота */
var anima = `<animateTransform id="at"
    attributeName="transform"
    begin="0s"
    dur="20s"
    type="rotate"
    from="0"
    to="360"
    repeatCount="indefinite"
        />`;

/* шаблон картинки из которой будет обрезаться сектор */
var image = `<image xlink:href="[path]" clip-path="url(#cp[number])" x="-100" y="-100" width="100%" height="100%" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin slice"></image>`;

/* делаем все сектора, количество секторов равно количеству картинок */
MakeAllArks(40, 100, images.length);

/* функция расчёта всех секторов */
function MakeAllArks(dis1, dis2, number) {
  var angle = (2 * Math.PI) / number;
  for (var i = 0; i < number; i++) {
    MakeArc(dis1, dis2, i * angle, angle, i);
  }
}

/* функция расчёта сектора */
function MakeArc(dis1, dis2, angleStart, angle, number) {
  var sumAngle = angleStart + angle;

  /* далаем расчёт основных точек сектора на основе функции поворота */
  var point1 = RotateVector({
    x: 0,
    y: dis1
  }, angleStart);
  var point2 = RotateVector({
    x: 0,
    y: dis2
  }, angleStart);
  var point3 = RotateVector({
    x: 0,
    y: dis2
  }, sumAngle);
  var point4 = RotateVector({
    x: 0,
    y: dis1
  }, sumAngle);

  /* создаём элемент пути */
  var path = document.createElementNS(svgNS, "path");

  /* путь сектора на основе расчёта точек */
  var d = `M ${point1.x} ${point1.y} L ${point2.x} ${point2.y} A ${dis2} ${dis2} 0 0 1 ${point3.x} ${point3.y} L ${point4.x} ${point4.y} A ${dis1} ${dis1} 0 0 0 ${point1.x} ${point1.y}`;

  path.setAttribute("d", d);

  /* добавляем анимацию поворота */
  path.innerHTML = anima;

  /* создаём вырезку с путём */
  var clipPath = document.createElementNS(svgNS, "clipPath");
  clipPath.setAttribute("id", "cp" + number);
  clipPath.appendChild(path);

  /* добавляем вырезку на холст */
  all.appendChild(clipPath);

  /* создаём картинку которая будет показана по вырезке на основе шаблона */
  var group = document.createElementNS(svgNS, "g");
  group.innerHTML = image.replace("[path]", images[number]).replace("[number]", number);

  /* добавляем картинку на холст */
  svg.appendChild(group);
}

/* функция поворота вектора с помощью матрицы поворота */
function RotateVector(vector, angle) {
  var cosa = Math.cos(angle);
  var sina = Math.sin(angle);
  var rez = {
    x: vector.x * cosa - vector.y * sina,
    y: vector.x * sina + vector.y * cosa
  };
  return rez;
}
```

```html
<svg id="svg" style="width:500px; height:500px" viewBox="-104 -104 208 208" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
  <defs>
    <pattern id="pat1" height="100%" width="100%" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
      <image xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/otCrT.jpg" x="0" y="0" width="100" height="100" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin slice"/>
    </pattern>
    <g id="all"></g>
  </defs>
  <circle cx="0" cy="0" r="40" fill="url(#pat1)"/>
</svg>

<!-- что бы StackOverflow не удалил эти картинки  -->
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/SaKBd.jpg" width="0">
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/cyQar.jpg" width="0">
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/gzQrR.jpg" width="0">
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/cyQar.jpg" width="0">
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/1KW4v.jpg" width="0">
```

Answer (score 2):

Анимация вращения колеса со смещением фонов секторов:

```css
path,
circle {
  stroke: black;
}

.p1 {
  fill: #d3dd00;
}

.p2 {
  fill: #d30000;
}

.p3 {
  fill: #682db4;
}

.p4 {
  fill: #60dd00;
}

.p5 {
  fill: #c9145e;
}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" width="500" height="500">
  <g>
    <path class="path p1" d="m167.64407 188.9322 7.98305 107.77119C223.6166 289.30677 269.2895 272.64387 298.0339 188.26695L192.25847 162.98729c-2.04033 11.777-7.16015 19.43869-24.6144 25.94491z"/>
    <path class="path p2" d="m130.38983 169.63983-95.131355 49.22881c33.190286 58.58315 80.570885 83.10953 140.368645 77.83475L167.64407 188.9322c-14.2749 0.62194-27.86502-1.35712-37.25424-19.29237z"/>
    <path class="path p3" d="m242.8178 41.245763c-0.66526 2.661017-61.24117 91.177607-61.24117 91.177607 8.28324 9.10114 13.63439 18.95888 10.68184 30.56392L298.0339 188.26695C305.49036 137.70818 297.69487 88.064523 242.8178 41.245763Z"/>
    <path class="path p4" d="m242.8178 41.245763-61.24117 91.177607c-12.1511-7.53907-24.70121-10.29013-38.10287-2.82244L78.08736 42.105458C127.00653 12.408637 180.14831 3.4410112 242.8178 41.245763Z"/>
    <path class="path p5" d="M143.47376 129.60093 78.08736 42.105458C12.358445 101.72182 8.4036304 160.50341 35.258475 218.86864l95.131355-49.22881c-4.64922-21.60596 2.82031-32.10305 13.08393-40.0389z"/>
    <circle cx="160" cy="155" r="35" fill="orange"/>
    <animateTransform attributeName="transform" type="rotate" values="0 161 155;360 160 155" dur="10s" repeatCount="indefinite"/>
  </g> 
</svg>
```

**P.S.** Вышло не слишком ровным, если присмотреться:)

Comment: По форме идеально к ВАЗ должно подойти)))

Comment: @MadFox, это хоть что-то))

Comment: согласен. Я к сожалению в SVG абсолютный ноль.

Comment: @MadFox, никогда не поздно начать:)

Comment: Интересная форма получилилась! А что означает когда так много чисел в `values` `animateTransform`.

Comment: @ДмитрийПолянин, rotate x y; rotate x y

Comment: @MadFox, месяц назад я тоже ничего не знал))

Comment: `x,y` Центр вращения?

Comment: @ДмитрийПолянин, да, в этом случае